# Django : Searching from different tables in django

Tags: python, django, django-search-lucene

I am trying to implement search functionality for the user in Django.

I can use `Q` for one table search but here the scenerio is different.

Here are my models:

```
Class Profile(models.Model)        
    name = models.OnoeToOneField(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    Tags   = models.ForeignKey(Tags)

class Category(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 100)
    sub_cat =  models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
```

I want to search a user who belongs to a categoey and/or a tag

But I am unable to find a way to do this. I don't want to use Haystack or Whoosh.

Please suggest to me some simple way to achieve this.

Comment: "Now want to search a user with name for a category and a tag ." Could you rephrase and elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try such a queryset ?

```
User.objects.filter(
    Q(profile__category__name__icontains=search_string) |
    Q(profile__Tags__name__icontains=search_string)
).distinct()
```

See [complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for details.

Note that I'm using `distinct()` to eliminate duplicate results because the same user can be selected for two reasons (each corresponding to a Q object).

(Of course, you should adapt `Tags__name` which I put as is for the sake of the example, but I don't have the source of the Tags model).

Comment: thanks i will try it now   . But could you please suggest me some good search module for big data

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy in fact:

Filter with category name:

```
Profile.objects.filter(category__name__iexact='category 1')
```

Filter with category id:

```
Profile.objects.filter(category__pk=27)
```

Filter with sub category name:

```
Profile.objects.filter(category__sub_cat__name__iexact='exact sub category name')
```